# Memory Leak Because of xmlbeans 2.6.0.jar

Tags: java, xlsx

I'm trying to do one project with `xlsx` file creation for that i included `xmlbeans 2.6.0.jar`. When i'm trying to restart the `glassfish` i'm getting the following error. Please any one go through this and help me out

```
Error:
Severe:   The web application [/test] created a ThreadLocal with
key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1]  
(value  
[org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1@4f7c1b38]) and 
a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value
[[java.lang.ref.SoftReference@51ec7f5b]]) but failed to remove it when 
the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over 
time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

Severe:   The web application [/test] created a ThreadLocal with 
key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$1] (value 
[org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$1@736da929]) and a value of 
type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value 
[java.lang.ref.SoftReference@60681b99]) but failed to remove it when 
the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over 
time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

Severe:   The web application [/test] created a ThreadLocal with 
key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1] (value 
[org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1@4fe26977]) and a value of type 
[java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value 
[java.lang.ref.SoftReference@7d46d177]) but failed to remove it when 
the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over 
time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [a known issue of XML Beans](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-502) library.

You may try following *Jochen Kemnade*'s suggestion:

> As a workaround, I moved the POI transformations to a dedicated thread pool which I shutdown when my webapp context is destroyed. This way, all the leaks go down with the pool and Tomcat's handler threads stay clean

Do the work inside and `Executor` and get rid of it.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to implement the solution? ie: How do we use a dedicated thread pool for anything related to the POI library?

Comment: @theyuv http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threads-pools-with-the-executor-framework all POI related code must be in the `Runnable` you pass to the `Executor`

Answer (score 0):

Since XMLBeans 3.1.0 (which is included starting with Apache POI 4.1.0), there is a method available to manually clear all thread locals from XMLBeans from the current thread:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.ThreadLocalUtil.clearAllThreadLocals()
```

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-502 and http://xmlbeans.apache.org/status.html